# python netCDF4 intermittent error either ok, invalid arguement or no such file

Tags: python, numpy

I have been successfully loading netCDF files in python for a couple of days now and today out of the blue my script is starting to fail.

I use a simple function to load netCDF variables as numpy arrays from a list of netCDF's in one of four subfolders. All four paths are the same apart from the subfolder name.

When I run an os.path.exists I get true but on some the netCDF4.Dataset(filename, 'r') will not work but on others it does as below only difference is filenames end in 2.nc and 3.nc

> > > os.path.exists(r'//WRON/working/SAF/LUTO/data/GLUCM/climate/climate_time_series_netcdf/evap/all/19830102.nc')
> > >
> > > True
> > >
> > > fi=netCDF4.Dataset(r'//WRON/working/SAF/LUTO/data/GLUCM/climate/climate_time_series_netcdf/evap/all/19830102.nc', 'r')
> > >
> > > error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "netCDF4.pyx", line 1328, in netCDF4.Dataset.**init** (netCDF4.c:6336)
RuntimeError: Invalid argument

> > > os.path.exists(r'//WRON/working/SAF/LUTO/data/GLUCM/climate/climate_time_series_netcdf/evap/all/19830103.nc')
> > >
> > > True
> > >
> > > fi=netCDF4.Dataset(r'//WRON/working/SAF/LUTO/data/GLUCM/climate/climate_time_series_netcdf/evap/all/19830103.nc', 'r')
> > >       `

Could I have corrupted netCDF files somehow, this was working this morning.

Comment: What package do you use for loading netCDF files? There are plenty of packages that support reading and writing netCDF files. You could give [pupynere](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pupynere/) a try and see if it works...

Comment: Thanks @Woltan I am currently using netCDF4 in python which was working and has suddenly developed these problems, I have not used pupynere before but I will have a look into it.